# Asus Smart Gesture auto disable touchpad when mouse connected, conflicts with touch display

Tags: laptop, mouse, synaptics-touchpad

I am using a laptop with a touch display and a mouse touchpad. Asus Taichi21 (smaller one).

The touchpad is not that optimal, so using the keyboard sometimes lead to a mouseclick (then hand areas touch the touchpad). I try to use the workaround to turn the touchpad off whenever I connect a mouse, but unfortunately the touchpad software seems to recognize the touch display as an input device, resulting in an always deactivated touchpad.

I know there is a keyboard shortcut to disable the touchpad manually, but I wonder if there is a way to not require that manual key combination every time. Something to filter the touchdisplay from being recognized by the touchpad software.